# Unable to insert record into the database

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have the followind code in my .NET application

```
public string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Storage.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
 string insertStatement = string.Empty;
            insertStatement = "INSERT INTO UserDetail(UserName, Password, IsRemember) Values('" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "','" + chkRemember.Checked + "')";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, con);
            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Storgae.mdf is the database which I have attached to the project. It's in the root directory.

Table structure

```
UserName NVarChar(50) NULL,
Password NVarChar(50) NULL,
IsRememberBit NULL
```

When I am running the query, it is returning **1** [No error, No exception] But when I checked into the database table, I found it empty.

Where I am wrong?

**Edit1**

When I changed the insertStatement to

```
insertStatement = "INSERT INTO UserDetail(UserName, Password) Values('" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "')"
```

Than also nothing is updated into the database. and execute non query returned *1* to me.

On keeping debugger on the insertStatement, I am getting the below Statement

```
INSERT INTO UserDetail(UserName, Password) Values('testName','TestPassword')
```

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you use SqlParameters, and never user string concatenations. Besides security concerns, performance reasons, it actually helps you a lot since some values cannot be represented in string so easily (inserting varbinary wouldn't be so straightforward)

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserDetail(UserName, Password, IsRemember) Values (@user, @pwd, @remember)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remember", isremember);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 absolutely - concatenating together a SQL statement should be punished - no one should keep on doing that! Use **parametrized queries** - **ALWAYS** (no exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

This section `'" + chkRemember.Checked + "')`

should be:

```
" + chkRemember.Checked + ")
```

i.e remove the single quotes around the final bit / boolean parameter.

Comment: I removed the ' ' for the chkRemember but now I am getting this error *The name "True" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.*

Comment: You need to use 1 for True and 0 for False `(chkRemember.Checked ? "1" : "0")`

Comment: I changed insertStatement to *insertStatement = "INSERT INTO UserDetail(UserName, Password, IsRemember) Values('" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "', " +(chkRemember.Checked? "1": "0")+ ")";* but no luck :-( [No error, No exception but unable to save data into the database]

Answer (score 0):

In respect to your Edit 1 you need to provide a default value for `IsRememberBit` in your database if you do not want to include it in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. Can you run SQL Profiler on the database, run the app and check what SQL queries are getting fired? Check to see if the Insert statement in your code is getting triggered.
My assumption is the issue might possibly be with the Connection string or you checking the wrong database. No hard feelings but I am used to doing that occasionally :)

Comment: Thanks! But I have stolen the connection string from the Data Source where it's claiming test connection successfull.